# switch between applications in silk4j

Tags: silktest, microfocus

I have a test thant launches a desktop application and from this application a browser application with authentication window is launched. The problem is when running the test it executes all steps that are related to the desktop application and when it comes to the browser it fails to detect it 
any help?

Comment: Can you see your browser if you select "Edit Application Configurations" item in Silk4J menu? If not, you will need to add it.

Comment: I added it but it didn't change anything. Still the same problem

Comment: Is the problem with the web content, or the authentication window? Each browser treats the authentication window differently. For some browsers you need to enable Microsoft Accessibility in order to automate it.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Silk Test and which browser + version are you testing against? As older versions of Silk Test may not provide support for the more recent browser versions. That's why it is recommended to stay version current.

Also if you log an incident via supportline@microfocus.com we would be happy to have a look at the issue in detail.

Answer (score 0):

After desktop application steps, to connect to the browser application (which has been opened through desktop app) you can use below code,

Desktop.attach("\BrowserApplication");

Desktop.< window >find ("\BrowserWindow[@caption='']").setActive();